# How are the Etrian Odyssey cataclysms connected?

Tags: etrian-odyssey-series

The *Etrian Odyssey* series of dungeon crawlers involves exploring labyrinths of various post-cataclysmic civilizations.

In the first game, *Etrian Odyssey*, you discover that the tree you've been exploring was engineered to fix pollution caused by some cataclysm. (Then the tree itself grew too large, causing a second disaster.)

In the second game, *Heroes of Lagaard*, you discover a "floating castle" - effectively a space station - where scientists were trying to engineer creatures able to survive after some cataclysm. The characters in the game are also aware of your exploits in *EO1*, so this definitely takes place in the same world and after the first game.

In the third game, *The Drowned City*, you are exploring a city sunk beneath the waves, one hundred years after a massive flood. Supposedly the cataclysm was caused by sinking the city to stop monsters called Deep Ones. However, the narrators in this game are the least reliable of the series.

Was the event 100 years before the third game the cause of the cataclysm of the first and second game, placing the third game long before the first two? Or was there another disaster, before that, which puts all three games around the same time?

Comment: Do the first and second games hint at how long after the cataclysm they are?

Comment: @Kevin: I don't remember any mention of specific dates; I'm hoping someone else does. It feels like it's been "many generations" at least.